# React Router - Auth based redirecting

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am building a login page example to improve my react skills. However, I couldn't figure out an issue about React Router. I successfully get authenticated and app takes me to the protected page but when I refresh the  page in this protected page , it shows me blank page.

The same thing happens when I try to write the protected URL manually. (blank screen)

Here is the PrivateRoute

```
    export const PrivateRoute = ({ 
        isAuthenticated, 
        component: Component,
        ...rest  
    }) => (
       <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
           if (isAuthenticated) {
               return <Component {...props} />
        }
        else {
            return <Redirect to="/" />
        }

    }} />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state.userReducer.token);
    return {
        isAuthenticated: !!state.userReducer.token
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Here is the PublicRoute

```
export const PublicRoute = ({ isAuthenticated, component: Component,  ...rest}) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => {
        if (isAuthenticated) { 
          return <Redirect to="/logged" /> 
        }
        else {
          return <Component {...props} />
        }
    }} />
  );

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: !!state.userReducer.token
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PublicRoute);
```

AppRouter

```
const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginForm} exact />
            <PrivateRoute path="/logged" component={LoggedPage} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
export default AppRouter;
```

And finally the last one that I create AppRouter

```
const  jsx = (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
)
ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I appreciate any suggestions, thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like state is stored in the memory. And when you refresh the page memory got cleaned and you end up in case where you are not authorized. If this is the case you could save store or at least token somewhere like sessionStorage or localStorage.

Comment: In addition, blank screen means that there could an error which you could see in the console of the DevTools of your browser. My rough guess is that state.userReducer.token is causing an error something like: "Cannot get token of undefined".

Comment: Yes, you are totally right but I expect to see the "/" route when I refresh the page because as you said state is on temporary memory and when I refresh It gets away. But it shows nothing instead. I also checked the DevTools and it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I don't know what is the project setup. If it is only index.html then it won't work because react router is using History API to override browser navigation. Without History API browser would try to navigate to /logged and it would return sort of 404 because there is no document available for such route. that's why people are using hashed routes, like #/logged to prevent such situation with only one index.html file.

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: Yes, I have only one file which is index.html. I also checked the auth example on the docs you sent me. It totaly does what I want to do. However, my code doesn't work in a proper way. The docs doesn't use the hashed route though.

Comment: I found a temporary solution to this while checking react devdools. When I remove exact from the PublicRoute, it returns to the PublicRoute after refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When page refreshes it loses its states as well as your login status. You should put some data to local storage to keep your session information. Before dispatching action about login I save users credentials to local storage. 
Whenever page reloads I fetch data from local storage and dispatch it as a login action. So I keep my session open.

```js
export function signInUser(user) {
  let userEmail = user.email;
  let userPassword = user.password;
  let credentials = {
    email: userEmail,
    password: userPassword
  };
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .request({
        method: "post",
        url: loopBack + "/blogusers/login?include=user",
        data: credentials
      })
      .then(response => {
        //sets user data to local storage
        localStorage.setItem("id", response.data.id);
        localStorage.setItem("userId", response.data.userId);
        localStorage.setItem("userName", response.data.user.userName);
        localStorage.setItem("email", response.data.user.email);
        return dispatch(signInSuccess(response.data));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return dispatch(signInFailure(error));
      });
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
//if session information is lost it gets data from            localstorage and set user data
export function setToken() {
   return dispatch => {
    let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
    let userId = localStorage.getItem("userId");
    let userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
    let user = { id, userId, user: { email, userName } };
    return dispatch(signInSuccess(user));
  };
}
```

Comment: For the blank page after refresh It is normal to see a blank page. Because all your routes are virtual routes and server does not know about it. For the routes you can use some server side redirecting scripts.